# Hello, someone knows how to make 3D games with Python?

Tags: python

As the programming language that is Python I wanted to know if in addition to making games in 2d with pygame I can create 3D games with Python which would be much more attractive for people (I guess) thanks in advance.

Comment: Python is Turing complete. Go for it.

Comment: General programming discussions are off topic here. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely make 3D games in Python.

For example, PyOpenGL (http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) is a wrapper around the OpenGL library that will allow you to develop 3D graphics.

Panda3D (http://www.panda3d.org/) is a framework made specifically for 3D games.